# how can i check that api is called in angularjs without seen in network

Tags: angularjs

I have an API I want to ensure that api has called mean get alert "api hit" else "api does not meet"

```
$http.post('v1/xyz/eeee res')
.success(function () {
////
})
```

Comment: it seems that you You Didn't Showed Enough amount of research on your Post . when you Updated your post with enough research .. your down Vote Will Be Lifted .. Good Luck

Comment: Priya You Need to Edit your Post To Lift my  Down Vote .. Add Some Content You Understood from Below Answers and edit it .. i can lift my Down Vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Priya this is how it happens

Controller Coding :-

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.hello = {name: "Boaz"};
    $scope.newName = "";
    $scope.sendPost = function() {
        var data = $.param({
            json: JSON.stringify({
                name: $scope.newName
            })
        });
        $http.post("/echo/json/", data).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.hello = data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     // this isn't happening:
            $scope.hello=data;
            console.log('this is nt happening '+data.status);
     }) 
    }                   
})
```

Html Coding :-

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{hello}}

<form ng-submit="sendPost()">
    <input ng-model="newName"/>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

    </div>
```

Finally You can see the Error result in My Fiddle :-

http://jsfiddle.net/bkUEu/2589/

with error status also

Hint :- Just replace post end-Point with  : /echo/ Instead /echo/json/ 
 Let Me Know the result  ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the success method either way.Both methods have been deprecated.

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Here is the shortcut method

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Here is a longer `GET` method sample

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

[Official Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: You can use `.catch` instead of the second callback too, its only really syntactical sugar but when you have promise chains with multi stage error handling it helps to keep things sane and readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use console.log or alert like:

```
$http.post('v1/xyz/eeee res')
    .success(function () {
        console.log('api hit success')
    })
    .error(function () {
        alert('api hit error')
    })
```

Or you could use interceptors:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            // statement to check if you are hitting your api
            if (config.url.startsWith('/v1'))
            alert('api hit')
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes I did but onclicking $http.post('v1/xyz/eeee res') is not calling above code works for success process and error process not for particular api hitting

Comment: you sure you getting error status 400 ? and Error Response Sending from Server side  ?

Comment: You could use request interceptors, these ones intercept each request you perform and you can simply put log or alert there.